# Best practice for subscribing to events of a control in a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ControlTemplate` for a custom control, which looks like this (simplified):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="CustomControl">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate TargetType="CustomClassA">
                <TextBlock Text={Binding ClassASpecificProperty}" />
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate TargetType="CustomClassB">
                <TextBlock Text={Binding ClassBSpecificProperty}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The beauty of  this is, that the specific `Content`, dependent on its type (A or B), is shown differently, caused by the `DataTemplate`s, defined for each type.

However. Sometimes there are not just `TextBlock`s. Imagine there was buttons in these DataTemplates. Sometimes you'd like to subscribe to `Click` events with certain methods. But these control templates are usually in a `ResourceDictionary`, so there is no *code behind* for putting methods for the correspoding `Click` handlers.

I saw three different solutions, yet:

- Creating a CustomResourceDictionary with code behind file attatched
- Override the `OnApplyTemplate` method (I don't really understand this, though) and subscribe to events programmatically
- Work with attatched messages and handle UI logic in the "ViewModel". *Ugly!*

What is the best practice to achieve this? Or are there even "better" solutions? And what about performance?

Comment: Have you considered using Commands?

Comment: Maybe chosing the `Button` control was not quite fitting for this purpose. It's not about implementing commanding in this place, because I'd like to subscribe for events like `SelectionChanged` event, *as well* (hope this one exists on e.g. a `ComboBox`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) to bind your buttons and whatnot to commands in the ViewModel.

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public DelegateCommand MyCommand {get;set;} //INotifyPropertyChanged, etc.

private void ExecuteMyCommand()
{
    //Do stuff here.
}

public MyViewModel()
{
    MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteMyCommand);
}
```